# Libtool passing incompatible flags to Microsoft's C/C++ compiler

Tags: visual-studio-2010, autotools, libtool

We are attempting to use Libtool, in conjunction with the full compliment of GNU Build System tools, to produce 'DLL's for Windows 7 32bit. To be more specific, we are attempting to produce Matlab modules.

Inexplicably, Autotools does two very contradictory things:

1) It recognizes that the C/C++ tool-chain that will be used is "msvc7". Thus, it is aware that I am using Microsoft's compilers instead of GCC.

2) It passes: -Xlinker to 'cl'.

Not surprisingly, 'cl' complains about unrecognized options. This issue would be almost tolerable if one of the appearances of 'Xlinker' was not followed by:

```
.libs/AverageFilter.mexw32
```

The result is the almost funny error:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1149: output filename matches input filename
```

Can anyone explain this behavior or offer suggestions on how to remedy it?